# How to access stopped container's file system on k3s?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a local Kubernetes cluster running with k3s and want to access the filesystem of a stopped Pod. The Pod originates from a CronJob and I want to investigate further why the Job failed.

For a "regular" Kubernetes setup, I would have tried to access the file system via the `docker` cli. With k3s, however, `docker ps` on the machine returns an empty list. From what I understand, k3s uses containerd, but I could not figure out how to inspect "containerd"-containers. My Google-fu missed me. :/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to enter the filesystem to check why `Job` failed.

When you are creating `job` it automatically creates `pod`. Example based on [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#running-an-example-job).

```
$ sudo k3s kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/job.yaml
job.batch/pi created
```

In the meantime it created pod (in the meantime ive created alias **kk="sudo k3s kubectl"**)

```
$ kk get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pi-796ng                 0/1     Completed   0          55s

$ kk get jobs
NAME      COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
pi        1/1           7s         30s
```

**1.** To check what happen inside the pod you can check it by

```
$ sudo k3s kubectl logs <pod_name> -c <container_name>

$ kk logs pi-796ng -c pi
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647...
```

**2.** Describe pod / describe job

`$ sudo k3s kubectl describe pod <pod_name>`

`$ sudo k3s kubectl describe job <job_name>`

If they are in different `namespace` then `default` you need to add `-n <namespace>` flag to query

**3.** Kubernetes events

Execute command

`$ sudo k3s kubectl get events`

It will show you all events from your `Kubernetes` cluster.

Many troubleshooting factors might also depends on your `Job` spec. For example `.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `.spec.backoffLimit`. More info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup).

Comment: Thanks @PjoterS for the detailed explanations. I already have access to the Pod's log, description and k8s events. However, the Job stores files in the file system that are not visible in the log. In my case: I'm running browser UI-tests using cypress.io, which stores videos of the test run which I'd like to see.

Comment: (Addendum: I will store the videos on storage in the future, but I'd like to look at the video of a past failed job in particular)

Comment: I think the only option here is use some Persistent Volume to save there these videos: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

Comment: Thanks PjoterS! I was afraid that it is not possible to access the files post-mortem and will put them on a Persistent Volume in the future.

Comment: What if the pod does not write logs to stdout but writes it to filesystem instead? (the pod is third-party)